# Import paddleHub: AttributeError: module 'paddle' has no attribute 'version'

Tags: paddle-paddle, paddleocr

I try to run paddleHub in my colab, but I face a question

`import paddlehub as hub`

the error
`AttributeError: module 'paddle' has no attribute 'version'`

I try to import 2.0 up version but it's still fail.

I try to import 2.0 up version but it's still fail.

`!git clone https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR.git !pip install paddleocr !pip install paddlepaddle !pip install paddlehub`

or

`! pip install -i https://pypi.org/simple/ paddlehub`

or

`!pip install paddlehub==2.0.0 -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple`